# Shrinking icon image in tableView cell

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I have an array of png icons homeIcons[] that load into the cells of my tableView. Unfortunately, they are too big and want them to shrink a bit. Trying to shrink them with this code:

```
    let cellIcon = UIImage(named: homeIcons[indexPath.row])
    cell.imageView!.frame = CGRect(x: cell.imageView!.frame.origin.x, y: cell.imageView!.frame.origin.y, width: cell.imageView!.frame.size.width / 2, height: cell.imageView!.frame.size.height / 2)    
    cell.imageView!.image = cellIcon
```

Changing the frame width and height doesn't do anything. Is there anyway to change the size of my icons or am I forced to redraw my images?

Comment: you can set content mode to image view by, `cell.imageView!.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit`

Answer (score 0):

Better if can add auto layout constraint to your imageview from storyboard.
or try calling `layoutIfNeeded()` after setting new frame.